# Как склеить два адреса

Tags: yii2

Путем создания отдельных классов правил сейчас вот такой запрос

```
Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/film/category/onefilm','id'=>$model->slug_film])
```

формирует такой адрес

```
http://film.lc/serials/serial-Druzba-narodov/
```

но если в адресной строке набрать вот так

```
http://film.lc/serial/category/oneserial?id=serial-Druzba-narodov
```

то переход так же состоится на такуюже страницу как и по этому адресу

```
http://film.lc/serials/serial-Druzba-narodov/
```

можно ли это как то склеить что бы ввод в адресной строке `http://film.lc/serial/category/oneserial?id=serial-Druzba-narodov` переходил на этот адрес `http://film.lc/serials/serial-Druzba-narodov/`
из классов правил ставлю только роутинг

```
 public function createUrl($manager, $route, $params)
    {
        if ($route === 'film/category/onefilm') {
            if (isset($params['id'])) {
                return 'films/'.$params['id'].'/';
            }
        }elseif($route === 'film/category/list'){
            if(isset($params['slug'])&&isset($params['page'])&&isset($params['per-page'])){
                return 'film/'.$params['slug'].'?page='.$params['page'].'&per-page='.$params['per-page'].'/';
            }elseif (isset($params['slug'])) {
                return 'films/'.$params['slug'].'/';
            }
        }...
        return false;  // данное правило не применимо
    }
```

Comment: >> _но если в адресной строке набрать вот так_ - то что?

Comment: @withoutname спасибо за замечание внеси изменения

Comment: Для генерации url, в Yii2 предусмотрен хелпер `Url`, который более лаконичен.

Comment: @withoutname не спорю просто так уже написано меять слишком долго будет. Но к делу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `rules` для компонента `urlManager` необходимо прописать следующие правило:

`//...
 rules => [
     //...
    'serials/<id:[\w-]+> => 'serial/category/oneserial',
 ]`

После этого все, что после `serials` будет доступно в параметре `id`.

Comment: у меня есть целый клас правил и он не помогает могу его выложить

Comment: @Sergalas, давайте посмотрим. И уточните пожалуйста, что вы хотите получить. Не совсем понятно.

Comment: внес изменения я бы хотел чтобы при наборе в адресной строке http://film.lc/serial/category/oneserial?id=serial-Druzba-narodov  переходило на адрес http://film.lc/serials/serial-Druzba-narodov/ ну ли если где-то есть затерянная ссылка вида http://film.lc/serial/category/oneserial?id=serial-Druzba-narodov  по её клику переходило на http://film.lc/serials/serial-Druzba-narodov/

Comment: @Sergalas, простите, а зачем метод `createUrl` было переопределять?Он работает отлично с правилами, которые пишутся в `rules`.
Если вы его переопределили, то ясно, что он не будет корректно работать с правилами, которые вы пишите.

Comment: в документации в примере создания классов правил для поиска по базе переопределялись два метода createUrl и parseRequest и вроде где-то в просторах интернета нашел что это обязательно.  А это важно для того что бы решить мою проблему. Просто пока я выхода не нашел. Мне бы хот направление указать.

Comment: @Sergalas, `urlManager`, как класс, на поиск по БД никак не влияет. Важно лишь то, как вы будите использовать для поиска входные параметры в моделе и контроллере. Рекомендую вам пересмотреть структуру, т.к. переопределив методы `urlManager` вы от динамики, перешли к статике и в дальнейшем, к примеру, если вы захотите добавить мультфильмы, вам придется снова идти и править  `urlManager`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44091/discussion-between-sergalas-and-withoutname).